# Inserting Arabic text in a CSV

Tags: notepad++, csv, notepad, arabic

I have a strange issue which is killing me.

I have a CSV file that is UTF-8. It is made up of some text fields and numeric fields. When I open the file in Notepad/Notepad++ and try to add Arabic text to it, it behaves very strange. An extract of the text is below:

`,14602,Jeddah,Project#1,62370.00,210000.00,Credit,`

When I try to add arabic text after Jeddah in the same field it works fine, but only because the field after is also a text field.

`14602,Jeddah / تاريخ,Project#1,62370.00,210000.00,Credit,`

But when I try to add arabic text after Project#1, it automatically moves the arabic text to the beginning of the next text field

`14602,Jeddah / تاريخ,Project#1 / تاريخ,62370.00,210000.00,Credit,`

Does anyone know what the heck is going on? I am trying to load data into a DB after i insert the arabic, but this is making it impossible...

Comment: Try to switch the character set under Encoding > Character Sets > Arabic (try all options).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Notepad++ is not an MS Office application.

Answer (score 0):

> **Does anyone know what the heck is going on?**

As suggested by the comment of Dr Moishe Pippik, you have a mixture of left-to-right scripts and right-to-left scripts.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) says

> Many computer programs fail to display bi-directional text correctly.

---

> **it automatically moves the arabic text to the beginning of the next text field**

The beginning of a right-to-left field is not where a left-to-right person might expect it to be. For example, using keyboard arrow-keys to move a cursor through a mixed LTR and RTL text can be quite exciting, especially when one or more of the scripts uses combining characters.

---

If you are a fluent native writer of both Arabic and English, you will already know all the above. New readers of this question might not be. This answer should at least help them.